# how to load one html file into div tag of another html file when link is clicked

Tags: html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.ajax') .click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        $('#content').load( 'abc.html' );
    });
});
</script>
<div id="content">
    <p>Here comes some content</p>
</div>
<div><a href="#" class="ajax">Link</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the code, i want to load abc.html content inside  with id="content" when link inside  is clicked.
This code does not work. Can anyone please help me..

Comment: Please be more specific than "does not work". What do your browser's developer tools say? Are there any error messages in the console? Can you see the request being made in the Net tab?

Comment: Where you have a string value of 'abc.html' do you really mean `$('#abc').html()`.  This would give you `$('#content').load($('#abc').html());`

Comment: @quentin:neither it shows any error nor getting desired result.

Comment: @ColinBacon — Since there isn't a `<foo id="abc">http://example.com/</foo>` in the document, that seems highly unlikely.

Comment: @colinBacon: i want abc.html file to be loaded so is that a syntax to get that???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your syntax is fine... This is probably a path issue. Remember that using "abc.html" as the path means that you are looking for a file called "abc.html" in the **current directory**.

For confirmations sake, check that abc.html is not empty, then make sure it is in the same folder as the calling file (or specify the correct path to the file). If that then works, then I suggest reading up on [Absolute vs. Relative paths/URLs](https://www.google.com/search?q=absolute%20vs.%20relative%20urls).

Comment: yup it is on the same directory and also it is loaded on the page but what i want is it should be loaded inside div tag

Comment: ...it should be doing that. http://api.jquery.com/load/ "Load data from the server and place the returned HTML **into** the matched element."

Comment: @Brainser what is actually happening? If the content is loading on the page, where is it loading too? You really need to start providing more information.